# Images with relative src not found in jQuery Mobile wrapped with iOS Phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

**Issue**

I have a strange issue with jQuery Mobile wrapped in Phonegap on iOS. My app consists of two pages, the second page being AJAX-loaded. On both pages I have images with a relative source like this

```
<img src="../images/myImage.png" />
```

On the first page, the image is displayed correctly. On the second page, the image is not found.

**Explanation**

I checked the src of both images with Weinre. It seems like Phonegap uses the data-url of the jQuery Mobile page div as prefix to the relative source. This works on page 1

```
file://path/to/app/html/../images/myImage.png
```

but not on page 2

```
file://path/to/app/html/page2../images/myImage.png
```

Why does Phonegap use the data-url on iOS?

**Environment**

What confuses me is that this problem **only occurs in iOS Phonegap**. It works fine in any browser and in Android Phonegap. It is a very basic "Hello World" like app with a standard jQuery Mobile page.

**Solutions**

I tried using the base tag, didn't work. I tried setting up the project again from scratch, didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Apparently jQuery Mobile identifies linked resources as external, if they don't have a file name suffix like ".html". My files were named without any suffixes.